# Call getPid to obtain node pid via XMLRPC in C++

Tags: ros, pid, xmlrpc, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to get the process IDs for all ROS nodes via the `getPid` [ROS Slave API](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Slave_API). I have been able to run the following:

```
XmlRpc::XmlRpcValue args, result, payload;
args[0] = "name of some node";
ros::master::execute("getPid", args, result, payload, true);
```

Unfortunately, this snippet appears to return the pid of rosmaster, and is independent of the args value I pass in.

I tried creating my own `XmlRpc::XmlRpcClient` instance with master host and port but different URIs. I cannot figure out how to get access to node URIs. If I do get them, I am not convinced that my approach works

```
std::string method = "getPid";
XmlRpc::XmlRpcClient* c = ros::XMLRPCManager::instance()->getXMLRPCClient(master_host, master_port, uri);
c->execute(method.c_str(), request, response);
```

Has anyone been successful here in the past? I found the following [Python approach](https://answers.ros.org/question/271776/how-can-i-retrieve-a-list-of-process-ids-of-ros-nodes/), but would very much like to do it in C++. I am using kinetic.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/315693/call-getpid-to-obtain-node-pid-via-xmlrpc-in-c++/) by [timwheeler](https://answers.ros.org/users/40038/timwheeler/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2019-02-14

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would think the result you receive from the master makes total sense right now, as you're asking it (ie: the master) to return its `pid`.

Haven't done this myself in C++, but I would imagine the control flow being similar to Python:

1. retrieve all node names from the master
2. retrieve URIs for all returned names
3. construct clients for all URIs
4. invoke `getPid` on all clients

---

Edit:

> "I cannot figure out how to get access to node URIs" - do you know how to do step (2) of what you suggest?

You can use `lookupNode` in the [Master API](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Master_API).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-02-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [timwheeler](https://answers.ros.org/users/40038/timwheeler/) on 2019-02-15**:
"I cannot figure out how to get access to node URIs" - do you know how to do step (2) of what you suggest?

**Comment by [timwheeler](https://answers.ros.org/users/40038/timwheeler/) on 2019-02-19**:
Perfect, thank you.

**Comment by [marinamrr](https://answers.ros.org/users/60202/marinamrr/) on 2020-09-28**:
Could someone please write  working template of this working? I get the URI, but the "getPID" call fails:

```
// Get URI of the node
XmlRpc::XmlRpcValue args, result, payload;
args.setSize(2);
args[0] = "caller_name";
args[1] = "node_name";
ros::master::execute("lookupNode", args, result, payload, true);

// Make new client of node
std::string uri = result[2];
XmlRpc::XmlRpcClient* client =
ros::XMLRPCManager::instance()->getXMLRPCClient(ros::master::getHost(), ros::master::getPort(), uri.c_str());

// Get PID of the node
XmlRpc::XmlRpcValue request, response;
request.setSize(1);
request[0] = "node_name";
client->execute("getPid", request, response);
```

The client execute call (last line) always returns false, am I missing something here?

**Comment by [aravindsaiUR](https://answers.ros.org/users/60815/aravindsaiur/) on 2021-05-19**:
Be sure to close the client created by the XmlRpc::XmlRpcClient, since it opens a socket for every client created. In case you run this in loop, you could get "Too many files opened" error or "Error:24" especially in linux. Since for each client a socket is created and sockets are defined as file descriptors in linux. This will be a memory leak. So always close an opened client after processing. Releasing the client connection is recommended.

```
ros::XMLRPCManager::instance()->releaseXMLRPCClient(xclient);
```